# Since I added this function to my code it hasn't stopped running. [VBA]

Tags: vba, logic

My function iterates through a multidimensional array and has to satisfy a condition. The array contains 1's and 0's. For the ones it can only be printed consecutively with atleast 4 ones and atmost 9. i.e. 1111 or 111111 allowed but not 11 or 11111111111. Between the ones there has to be atleast 12 zeroes eg, 1111000000000000111111.  Also within 7 sets of ones there has to be 36 consecutive 0's. The latter is the constraint I added and hasn't seemed to stop running. This is for a roster tool so workdays = 7 and maxconsecutivehours = 36.

```
Dim i, j, m, counter1, counter2, counter3, counterA, remainder As Double

For i = 1 To UBound(posSolution, 1)
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0
        For j = 1 To UBound(posSolution, 2)
            If posSolution(i, j) = 0 Then
                Do Until posSolution(i, j) = 1
                    counter1 = counter1 + 1
                Loop
                    counter2 = counter2 + 1
                        If counter1 >= maxConsecutiveHours Then
                            j = j + 24 * (workDays - counter2)
                            counter1 = 0
                            counter2 = 0
                        Else
                            remainder = maxConsecutiveHours - counter1
                            counter3 = j
                                Do Until posSolution(i, counter3) = 1
                                    counter3 = counter3 - 1
                                Loop
                                    Do While posSolution(i, counter3) = 1
                                        counter3 = counter3 - 1
                                        counterA = counterA + 1
                                    Loop
                                        If (counterA - remainder) >= minWorkHours Then
                                            For m = (counter3 + counterA - remainder) To counter3 + counterA
                                                posSolution(i, m) = 0
                                            Next m
                                            j = m + 24 * (workDays - counter2)
                                            counter1 = 0
                                            counter2 = 0
                                            counter3 = 0
                                            counterA = 0
                                        End If
                        End If
            End If
        Next j
Next i
```

I'm interested in understanding why the code is still running since I added this function.

Answer (score 1):

This particular bit of code can never exit:

```
Do Until posSolution(i, j) = 1
    counter1 = counter1 + 1
Loop
```

The value of `posSolution(i, j)` is never changed inside the loop, so if it doesn't equal 1, it will repeatedly increment `counter1` until it overflows. You have it implicitly declared as a `Variant` here:

```
Dim i, j, m, counter1, counter2, counter3, counterA, remainder As Double
```

Only `remainder` is explicitly a `Double` - everything else is a `Variant`.  If you put multiple declarations on the same line, you need to specify a type for ***each one***:

```
Dim i As Double, j As Double, m As Double, etc...
```

Because `counter1` is a `Variant`, it will repeatedly get promoted until it ***is*** a `Double`, and will run out of precision before it will overflow.